# Team Foundation Server 2010 / MSBuild: Error parsing the nested project section in solution file

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm trying to set up a nightly build for one of my company's products. When I execute the build, it fails after 45 or so seconds, giving the error "Error parsing the nested project section in solution file.

This is the log from the build:

> Delete Binaries Directory
>
> 00:17 Delete Workspace
>
> 00:00 Delete Sources Directory
>
> 00:00 Create Workspace
>
> 00:18 Get Workspace
>
> 00:01 Create Label Label [label]
>   (version W60_2_VMCORPTFS01;CL\me) was
>   successfully created.
>
> 00:04 Compile, Test, and Associate
>   Changesets and Work Items
>
> 00:04 Compile and Test
>
> 00:03 Run MSBuild for Project
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
>   /nologo /noconsolelogger
>   "e:\localstore\Productname_2.0\Product\Product.sln"
>   /m:1 /fl
>   /flp:"logfile=e:\localstore\ThisSpecificBuild\Product\Product.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal"
>   /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
>   /p:OutDir="C:\Builds\2\Product\ThisSpecificBuild\Binaries\"
>   /p:Configuration="Debug"
>   /p:Platform="Any CPU"
>   /p:VCBuildOverride="e:\localstore\Productname_2.0\Product\Product.sln.Any
>   CPU.Debug.vsprops" 
>   /dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
>   2010\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/2934;InformationNodeId=1175609;TargetsNotLogged=GetNativeManifest,GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems,GetTargetPath;TFSUrl=http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
>   2010\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;"
>
> 00:00 Built
>   $/OMS/Branches/Product_2.0/Product/Product.sln
>   for default targets. 
>   e:\localstore\ThisSpecificBuild\Product\Product.sln
>   (1586): Error parsing the nested
>   project section in solution file.

And this is the log from MSBuild:

> Build started 7/6/2011 11:53:34 AM.
>   e:\localstore\ThisSpecificBuild\Product\Product.sln(1586):
>   Solution file error MSB5009: Error
>   parsing the nested project section in
>   solution file.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> e:\localstore\ThisSpecificBuild\Product\Product.sln(1586):
>   Solution file error MSB5009: Error
>   parsing the nested project section in
>   solution file.
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.19

The solution builds correctly from within Visual Studio.

Comment: So what are the lines in the solution file surrounding line 1586?

Comment: I was all excited because I hadn't thought of that, but it turns out there are only 942 lines in the solution file. I think that might be the right path, though.

Comment: Not a duplicate but has a very similar set of solutions to the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777583/msbuild-command-line-build-error-solution-file-error-msb5023-error-parsing-th

Answer (score 22):

Try to remove and then re-add some file, to cause sln file to be regenerated. This way I got build succeeded. My sln file was in an incorrect format for some reason.

Comment: Did the trick for me - added a new solution folder, saved, removed the solution folder again, saved.

Comment: Did the trick for me also - In my case sln file was wrong because of merge. Missing "EndProject"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777583/msbuild-command-line-build-error-solution-file-error-msb5023-error-parsing-th/37598456#37598456 better solution for me

Answer (score 4):

I just spent all afternoon on this and found a contributing factor. I found the entry in the .sln file referencing a project that did not exist in the solution. Nor was that phantom project's GUID referenced anywhere else in the .sln file.

Searching returned a couple tricks, such as http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/msbuild/thread/55ab07ef-9179-4cc6-b2d0-63fcf088d8ba

Those "seemed" not to work, as local builds still succeeded and the Team Build still failed. Then I noticed that line 6199 in my solution was *always* at fault, even though that line was changing over time. It turned out the Team Build Definition had **Clean Workspace** set to **Outputs** instead of **All**. After changing it to **All**, the Team Build worked again.

Answer (score 3):

If you have modified the file manually or through merged tool, there might be an empty line left, which is OK with Visual Studio compilation, but fails in automation builds.

Answer (score 0):

For me renaming my Project and shorten the projectnames helped. It seems that, depending in which target directory tfs is dropping your solution, the max. lenght 256 for file names can be exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and managed to sort it out:

1. Opened .sln in NotePad and found Guids
2. One of my projects wasn't closed ("EndProject" was missed)

Cheers, hope this can help anyone